# Prove that $(x^{\alpha})'=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

use the fact that $x^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha log(x)}$

I am close but I feel like I am missing a step here:

$(e^{\alpha log(x)})'$

using the product rule and taking the deriviative times the inside we get:

outside: $e^{\alpha log(x)}=x^{\alpha}$ whose derivative is $
\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$

but then the derivative of the inside is $\frac{\alpha}{x}$

combining the two gives:

$\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\frac{\alpha}{x}$

which is not correct what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want the function-of-a-function rule. And you mustn't assume the result while proving it.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative of $e^{\alpha \log(x)}$ is actually $e^{\alpha \log(x)} \frac{d}{dx}(\alpha \log(x))$ from chain rule which is nothing more than $\frac{\alpha}{x} e^{\alpha \log(x)}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes thank you i meant chain rule in the post but wrote down product rule?

Answer (score 1):

Must you use $x=e^{\ln x}$?  Personally I like using logarithmic differentiation instead:

\begin{align}
y&=x^\alpha\\
\ln y&= \ln x^\alpha\\
\ln y&=\alpha \ln x\\
\frac{d}{dx} (\ln y)&=\frac{d}{dx} \alpha\ln x\\
\frac1y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}&=\alpha\cdot\frac1x\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\alpha\cdot\frac1x\cdot y\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\alpha\cdot\frac1x\cdot x^\alpha\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

By definition,

$$(x^\alpha)'=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{(x+h)^\alpha-x^\alpha}{h} $$

If $\alpha \in{\mathbb N}$, then by the binomial theorem,

$$\dfrac{(x+h)^\alpha-x^\alpha}{h}=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2}hx^{\alpha-2}+\ ... +h^{\alpha-1}$$

As $h\to 0$, the terms with $h$ tends to $0$, hence

$$\forall{\alpha \in{\mathbb{N}}}, \; \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{(x+h)^\alpha-x^\alpha}{h}=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$$

Since
$(x+h)^{-\alpha}-x^{-\alpha}= \dfrac{x^{\alpha}-(x+h)^{\alpha}}{(x+h)^{\alpha}x^{\alpha}}\;,$

$$(x^{-\alpha})'=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{(x+h)^{-\alpha}-x^{-\alpha}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{x^{\alpha}-(x+h)^{\alpha}}{h(x+h)^{\alpha}x^{\alpha}}$$

Notice that $\dfrac{x^{\alpha}-(x+h)^{\alpha}}{h}=-(x^{\alpha})'$, and as $h \to 0,\; (x+h)^{\alpha} \to x^{\alpha}.$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{x^{\alpha}-(x+h)^{\alpha}}{h(x+h)^{\alpha}x^{\alpha}}=-\alpha x^{\alpha -1}\frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}}=-\alpha x^{-\alpha -1}$$

Let $\beta = -\alpha$, and we have

$$(x^{\beta})'=\beta x^{\beta -1}$$

By the formula for $a^n-b^n$,

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}-x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-1} ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}})^{\alpha-1-k} \;(x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}})^{k}}$$

Again, as $h \to 0$, $x+h \to x$, so
$${\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-1} ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}})^{\alpha-1-k} \;(x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}})^{k}}=\alpha x^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}}$$

Hence,

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}-x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}{h}=\frac{1}{\alpha} x^{\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}}$$

If we let $\gamma = \frac{1}{\alpha}$, we have

$$(x^{\gamma})'=\gamma x^{\gamma-1}$$

So we have

$$\forall{\eta\in{\mathbb Z}\cup \{\frac{1}{a}|a\in\Bbb Z\} },\;(x^{\eta})'=\eta x^{\eta-1}$$

By chain rule,

$$(x^{\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}})'=\eta_1 x^{\frac{\eta_1 -1}{\eta_2}}\frac{1}{\eta_2}x^{\frac{1}{\eta_2}-1}=\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}x^{\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}-1}$$

Therefore,

$$\forall{\omega\in \mathbb Q}, (x^{\omega})'= \omega x^{\omega -1}$$

EDIT: A way using $x^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha ln(x)}$:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{\alpha ln(x+h)}-e^{\alpha ln(x)}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{\alpha ln(x)} (e^{\alpha ln(\frac{x+h}{x})}-1)}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h}(e^{\alpha ln(\frac{x+h}{x})}-1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}((1+\frac{h}{x})^{\alpha}-1)$$

By the binomial expansion, we have 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}((1+\frac{h}{x})^{\alpha}-1)=\frac{\alpha}{x}$$

Hence, $$(x^{\alpha})'=\frac{\alpha}{x}x^{\alpha}=\alpha x^{\alpha-1} \;\;\forall{\alpha\in {\mathbb Q}}$$

Comment: You didn’t use $x^\alpha=e^{\alpha\ln x}$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule says that $\frac{d(f(y))}{dx}=\frac{d(f(y))}{dy}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$

Many people see this rule as the $dy$s cancelling out. However, it is not advised to look at it like that.

In your case $f(y)$=$e^y$, where $y=alog(x)$.

So, $\frac{d(f(y))}{dy}=\frac{d(e^y)}{dy}=e^y=e^{alog(x)}=x^a$

And $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(alog(x))}{dx}=\frac{a}{x}$

Multiply these together to get $ax^{a-1}$